# Apply LookAt change to position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I had a text which is a overlay text on the object.
I had applied LookAt to make it rotate face to the camera.
But because it's a overlay text on object so it should also RotateAround the object.
I don't know how should I calculate the angle to make it work like LookAt but changing the position instead of rotation.
Thank you.
Below is a drawing in case my describe is not clear.
[image]

Comment: Make an empty object and the text a child, move it forward the radius you want. Then just point the empty to look at the camera and the text will rotate because the look at turns the empty and the text will be whatever distance nearer than the empty.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Why haven't I thought of that lol